# How to draw LinearLayout in canvas?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, canvas, layout

[canvas.drawText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#drawText(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint)) draws text on the canvas. How can I draw a linear layout on the canvas?

Something like `canvas.drawLinearLayout()` would be excellent but it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really enough info provided about the state of the LinearLayout (has it been drawn already)

But if it has been drawn already then

`myLinearLayout.draw(canvas)`

will get the LinearLayout to draw itself the the specified canvas.

Comment: Excellent, thanks Andrew! Upvoted and accepted. yes it has been drawn already

Comment: However, the linearlayout appears small on the canvas. how can I make it bigger?

Comment: the original linear layout is much bigger

Comment: Again you don't provide enough info, the canvas might have a scale transform set on it. You really need to provide more code on how you create the linear layout and create and setup the canvas. But it will be drawn at the same size as before (as you are not re-measuring it and and have not re-laid it out)

Comment: ok. i created a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74008657/how-to-make-drawn-view-appear-bigger-on-canvas